# How to import an iCalendar event with diferent time zones

Tags: google-calendar, import, time-zone

On Google Calendar I'm able to *manually* create an event that *starts and ends in different time zones*:

[image: Manually entered Google Calendar Entry with different time zones at start and end]

I would like to recreate entries like this using the import feature in Google Calendar (`(gear) > settings > import & export > (select file) > import`).

I have tried the following, which does import, but the resulting calendar entry is incorrect:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Time - New York:20191207T124500
DTEND;TZID=Eastern European Standard Time - Cairo:20191208T050500
DESCRIPTION:Event starting NY 12:45pm (local time) - ending Eastern Europe 5:05am (local time)
LOCATION:Atlantic
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Flight
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The resulting entry makes incorrect assumptions about time zones, presuming the entries are zulu or something.

I have also tried to set the `TZID` parameter to things like "GMT-04:00", but those did not successfully import to Google Calendar at all.  And using `DTSTART:20191207T124500` or `DTSTART:20191207T124500Z` works, but doesn't do what I want.

My starting point for this endeavor was to export a calendar entry that had the time zone details, but that did not export with the time zone details (only exported in GMT+00:00 zulu).

So in summary, I'm able to import, just need to figure out how to import an event and have it show *different starting and ending time zones*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the TZIDs used in your iCal file, using the [VTIMEZONE component](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/vtimezone.html).

For example, add this block of code after `END:VEVENT` to define the "Eastern Time - New York" timezone:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Time - New York
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19671029T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19870405T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

The [iCalendar Validator](https://icalendar.org/validator.html) is a nice tool to make sure your iCal file conforms to RFC 5545.

Comment: I saw that I could define a time zone, but I thought that was quite tedious, with both the standard and daylight and associated rules.  I didn't know if I could get it right.  I need to understand where stock "VTIMEZONE" clips are located so I don't need to write them myself.

Comment: The code above is accurate for EST/EDT as of today (may change in the future depending on legislation). If this answered your question, please mark as accepted!

Comment: I was hoping you'd add where the current definitions of other time zones were.

Comment: Thanks. I could not find a resource after some quick googling. Sounds like a great idea for a github library.